# Gráfico de líneas usando Flot con datos de un MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estoy usando el plugin Flot para tener un gráfico de líneas con líneas (sales y purchases) como en [este ejemplo](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html) pero la data está en una base de datos MySQL y las obtengo vía AJAX, tengo esto:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="graph" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
```

**PHP:**

**sales.php**

```
<?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * from sales where YEAR(date)='2013'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $return = [];

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $return[] = [strtotime($row['date'])*1000,$row['amount']];
  }

  echo json_encode(array("label"=>"Sales","data"=>$return));
?>
```

**purchases.php**

```
<?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * from purchases where YEAR(date)='2013'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $return = [];

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $return[] = [strtotime($row['date'])*1000,$row['amount']];
  }
  echo json_encode(array("label"=>"Purchases","data"=>$return));
?>
```

Y en mi código JS obtengo esta información vía AJAX y lo pongo en un gráfico Flot habilitando tooltip dentro de una función llamada **show_chart** invocada dentro del **success** de AJAX:

```
function show_chart(labell,dataa) { 
 var dataset = [{label: labell,data: dataa}];

var chart_plot_01_settings = {
  series: {
    lines: {
      show: true,
      fill: true
    },
    splines: {
      show: false,
      tension: 0.4,
      lineWidth: 1,
      fill: 0.4
    },
    points: {
      radius: 3,
      show: true 
    },
    shadowSize: 2 
  },
  grid: { 
    verticalLines: true,
    hoverable: true,
    clickable: true,
    tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: '#717171'
  },
  colors: ["rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.38)", "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.38)"],
  xaxis: {
    tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
    mode: "time",
    tickSize: [1, "month"],
    //tickLength: 10,
    axisLabel: "Date",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 10
  },
  yaxis: {
    ticks: 8,
    axisLabel: "Amount",
    tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
  },
  tooltip: true,
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#graph"), dataset, chart_plot_01_settings);

    //Tooltip
    $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
        position: "absolute",
        display: "none",
        border: "1px solid #fdd",
        padding: "2px",
        "background-color": "#fee",
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body");

    $("#graph").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

        if (item) {
            var x = item.datapoint[0],
                y = item.datapoint[1];

            var date = new Date(x);

            $("#tooltip").html("Date: " + ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'+ date.getFullYear()+ " | Amount: "+y).css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5}).fadeIn(200);

        } else {
            $("#tooltip").hide();
        }

    });
 });

} //show chart

var purchases,sales;

$.ajax({url: "purchases.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp)
    {
        purchases = resp.data;
        var label1 = resp.label;
        show_chart(label1,purchases);       
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "sales.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp)
    {
        sales = resp.data;
        var label2 = resp.label;
        show_chart(label2,sales);
    }
});
```

El problema es que el gráfico sólo muestra una línea ya sea de Sales o  Purchases pero yo deseo que muestre ambas líneas en el gráfico como se muestra en el ejemplo.

¿Cómo puedo modificarlo?

Me gustaría su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente pude resolverlo uniendo los dos archivos php en uno solo y poner el resultado en un array final:

```
echo json_encode(array($return,$returnn));
```

En AJAX success:

```
success: function(resp)
{
  var result1 = resp[0];//purchases
  var result2 = resp[1];//sales
  show_chart(result1,result2);
}
```

Y en el function **show_cart**:

```
function show_chart(data1,data2) {
  var dataset = [{label: "Purchases",data: data1},{label: "Sales",data: data2}];
  //y continúa...
}
```